# How to plot success curves in MATLAB for evaluation of object tracking algorithm?

Tags: matlab, statistics, precision-recall

I am working on visual object tracking. I have calculated the suuccess rate but dont know how can i plot such curves in MATLAB. Please help me. Thank you

[image]

I have caluclated the success rate of algorithm.

Comment: are you asking how to use MATLAB to draw plots? what **specific** issue do you have with matlab's plotting feature?

Comment: Following up on @ChristophRackwitz's comment, have you read the documentation at [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)?

Comment: I have calculated precision or success rate. But i dont know how to get IoU threshold.

Comment: I have calculated precision or success rate. But i dont know how to get IoU threshold.

Comment: This seems to be a very specific question regarding "IoU threshold" and not a programming question. The way the question is asked, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.